# TcL - List editing

Tags: list, file, for-loop, tcl

I have this list of data coming from a FE analysis program. My problem is that the function in the FE programs who's writing the data do so by putting all the information on the same line.  I end up with a "list" of llength 1 with 10 000 entry on the same line. I would like to be able to put some sort of "enter" in between each of the data in the list. Each data do have the same length (# ofcaracter). The list goes something like this :
4.81941e-010 4.89941e-010 3.81941e-010 1.81341e-010 ... etc (on the same line)
I would like to do something like :

```
for {set i 1} {$i<=$length in list} {incr i 1} {
count 12 caracter then do a enter
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the list goes like what you've pasted how is its `llength` 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
join $list \n
```

?

This is based on the fact that there seems to be a space character between numbers, which means that the string is also a list of 10000 items.

Otherwise, you can put substrings in a list like this:

```
set list {}
for {set i 0} {$i < [string length $str]} {incr i 13} {
    lappend list [string trimright [string range $str $i $i+12]]
}
```

Documentation: [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Peter's answer, you can choose to replace space with new line:

```
set list [string map {" " "\n"} $list]
```